# Using Raw Data of EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt to create a PDF

Tags: windows, driver, postscript, printers, point-of-sale

i have following problem. For normal Printers i've created an application which gets data from a laserjet-printerdriver (redirected output with redmon). After Processing the data and generating a pdf document, the file is redirected to the orginal printer and being printed. For these actions i used the driver of a postscript capable printer.
All works fine.

But now i should use the same on a software which only prints to POS-Printers. So i created a printer with the Driver of EPSON TM-T88IV and redirected it to my application. The process should be the same: reading output, processing data, generate pdf, print on physical printer. My problem now is that i have raw data and don't know if it's possible to generate a postscript or pdf from it.

Possible solutions could be

- Does anyone know a POS printer, which supports postscript? (don't think that such really exist, but maybe..)
- Is there a way to edit the Laserjet driver, that it will appear as a POS Printer?
- a way to parse the Raw data to postscript

Does anyone have a solution or an idea how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a PostScript driver then use GhostScript to render the PostScript through the Epson driver. It won't be pretty but should work.

Comment: My problem is that i cannot find any PS Driver which is additionally a point-of-sale Printer. The external application does only allow POS-printers..